# Swift 3 - Cannot call value of non-function type '(response: Any, error Any)'

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire

I have written the following method in Swift 3

```
func postFormData(url : String, parameters: Parameters!, headers : HTTPHeaders!, completionHandler : (response : Any,  error: Any)) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method : .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in

            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status)
                {
                    let data = result as! NSDictionary
                    case 200:
                        if let result = response.result.value {
                            completionHandler(data)
                        }
                    default:
                        completionHandler(nil, data)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

1. I get an error at `completionHandler(data)` stating `Cannot call value of non-function type '(response: Any, error Any)'`
2. Is writing `completionHandler(nil, data)` to handle errors the best practice?

PS : I am new to `iOS` and `Swift 3`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You´re missing the return for your `completionHandler` `-> Void` and the parameter names, I added the defaults `_` here:

```
func postFormData(url : String, parameters: Parameters!, headers : HTTPHeaders!, completionHandler : (_ response : Any,  _ error: Any) -> Void ) {

    Alamofire.request(url, method : .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
        .responseJSON { response in
            if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
                switch(status)
                {
                    let data = result as! NSDictionary
                case 200:
                    if let result = response.result.value {
                        completionHandler(data)
                    }
                default:
                    completionHandler(nil, data)
                }
            }
    }

}
```

For the error part, I would have added an `onError` as , `onError: (NSError) -> Void)` and returned onError if an error occurs. So like this:

```
func postFormData(url : String, parameters: Parameters!, headers : HTTPHeaders!, completionHandler : (_ response : Any,  _ error: Any) -> Void, onError: (NSError) -> Void)
```

Answer (score -1):

Use below function Swift 3:

```
func postFormData(url : String, parameters: Parameters!, headers : HTTPHeaders!, completionHandler : (_ response : Any?,  _ error: Any?)-> Void) {

     Alamofire.request(url, method : .post, parameters: parameters, headers: headers)
    .responseJSON { response in

        if let status = response.response?.statusCode {
            switch(status)
            {
                let data = result as! NSDictionary
            case 200:
                if let result = response.result.value {
                    completionHandler(data, nil)
                }
            default:
                completionHandler(nil, data)
            }
        }
    }
}
```